# dart make `missing_enum_constant_in_switch` a compile error

Tags: flutter, dart

When having a non handled enum case in a switch statement in dart, the compiler only reports a warning which makes it tedious to find all places I need to adjust when adding a new enum case.

[image]

**How can I make the compiler report that as an error** so the build does not complete successfully and tells me all locations where I need to take care of the new case?

PS: I found it was an error before according to this [github issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25576), but they changed the severity from error to warning, but I found the argumentation "because it is documented as warning" very weak. To me this must be an error, like in other languages such as kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

In `analysis_options.yaml`, add this:

```
analyzer:
  errors:
    missing_enum_constant_in_switch: error
```

Comment: This enables the analyzer to report it as error, but the build still does complete and the compiler does not fail with an error.

Comment: I think that is as good as you are going to get. I tried searching for 'dart analyzer prevent build' but only got one solution which is aimed at CI rather than Visual Studio / Android Studio -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71661639/how-to-set-flutter-lint-rules-as-an-error-and-prevent-application-to-build